# Shell script with mysqldump

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

I wrote a shell script to automate mysqldump. 
I don't want my password to be entered in the script file. Can anyone suggest me an  alternative way to do this?

Comment: @anubhava ummm...would it be a good idea to keep the password in the ENV?

Comment: He would be already keeping it somewhere in cleartext I guess

Comment: Read it from a hidden file and make sure the file permission allows only you/sysadmin to read the file.I'm assuming you will have the execute permission to run the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the script interactively, then you can use `read` to read the password into an environmental variable, and then echo that password to mysqldump.

```
read -s -p 'password: ' password

echo "$password" | mysqldump ...
```

The password will be stored in plain text in memory but not elsewhere.

Alternatively as per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password) you can use an [option file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) to avoid giving the password on the command line. The file would contain something similar to the below:

```
[client]
# The following password will be sent to all standard MySQL clients
password="my_password"
```

Comment: I am setting up the script in crontab. So storing it in a variable is not a good option for me. If i can store in a file and change the permisiion of that file and specify the path in script, then thats great.

Comment: Looks like you can, see the part of my answer that starts "Alternatively"